# Does it matter how long ago you took a course for graduate school admissions

Tags: graduate-admissions, undergraduate

This might be a strange question, but I was curious how much weight goes into when you took a course.  I took some math courses 4-5 years ago and did well in them.  Will the fact that I took courses from that long ago carry less weight when applying to grad school?

Comment: how the answer to that Q change what you are going to do?

Comment: @aaaaaa I think it is OK to just be curious about something, without planning to change a course of action based on the answers.

Answer (score 1):

This depends a lot on what you've been doing in the interim. At one extreme, even if you had a solid coursework background, but have not been exercising it, or anything related, for the last decade, and admissions committee will worry that you're not up-to-speed.

At another extreme, if you did well in coursework and have been doing serious stuff subsequently, more-or-less related to your future goals, that's obviously a plus. That is, the "stale coursework" potential problem is *not* a problem for you since you've not only maintained, but improved, your chops meanwhile.

True, it's easier to flash a transcript to "prove" some knowledge or expertise, while professional knowledge or expertise is not universally set up to be "documentable".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit, probably not a lot. But it depends on what you are applying for and to where and what you have been doing since you took those courses.

Generally speaking, admissions doesn't depend on any single thing. Someone, perhaps a committee has to make a judgement about your likelihood of success in a particular degree program. Normally that includes lots of things.

But it would be more of a factor if the degree is highly dependent on the knowledge from those courses and you haven't been doing anything related or similar in the time in between. For some things it is easy to come back up to speed. For other things it is harder.

But the only way to know is to apply and listen to any feedback you get.

Comment: I got admitted to a PhD program over 25 years after my last formal college education. However, I suspect I was admitted more on the basis of what I had done in industry and my computer science GRE result than on ancient transcripts.

Answer (score 0):

This varies on a case by case basis: you can imagine that the contents of an electronics or genetics course from 10 years ago may now be stale, but maybe not for a vector calculus course.  The admissions committee will the the ultimate judge of that.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the institution’s policies, as well as the graduate committee in question.

I have been in settings where both *when* and *where* you took a class is factored into things, and sufficiently “stale” classes aren’t weighted particularly highly because the content, while valid, isn’t what would be taught now.

Using the molecular biology example in another answer, the field has moved fast enough that a course taken a decade ago is now actively *obsolete*, while for some other courses, it might not matter (for example, the foundational classes in my field are built on methods that haven’t changed much).

If the committee is using it to decide “Can you take classes in X and succeed?” it likely won’t matter. If they’re using those classes to go “Great, you’re already equipped with classes in X, Y and Z.” then it very much might.

Answer (score -1):

No, it does not matter when you took the course, so long as it is finished by the date required by the admissions policy.